# In the Plug-in spy in Eclipse, what information does the Active Help offer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the Plug-in spy in Eclipse, what information does the Active Help offer?

[image: Plug in Spy]

Answer (score 1):

Those are the IDs of the available context help for the view that you investigate. So if you use the main menu Help -> Dynamic help while that compare editor is focused, one of those 2 topics will be shown in the Help view on the right side of the IDE.

It may become a bit more clear if you use the Spy on a plugin manifest editor. There you will see help context ids for the plugin description page, the extensions page, the extension points page and so on.